# Embedding multiple files of different types into a single C# console application

Tags: c#

Edited to be clearer as to what I'm trying to do.

I have a console application that I'm working on that I want to do the following:

1) Run a msi installer to install a particular application

2) Copy an already written console application to the public folder on a Windows box

3) Schedule a Windows Task that runs the console application that was copied on a Schedule

I'm using the Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll library (3rd party) to create the code that sets up the task.  When I move the exe to an external machine it does not detect the dll that makes the task scheduler code work, does not seem to have access to the msi or the other console application either.

So I need a way to combine the two console application, the msi, and the dll into a single exe file that will run on any machine as intended.

I have all the code available from the two console applications available and can post it if needed.

Comment: You've posted a *lot* of code, but it's not clear what the problem is. What happens with what you've tried? What do you mean by "I can't seem to get it [...] into this single program to be redistributable"? Are you trying to create a setup exe, or just a console app that embeds various files as resources?

Comment: Trying to create a single exe that contains a console application, the dll that handles the task management stuff, and an msi.

Comment: But what should that exe be? An installer for the application? What's the purpose of the MSI? Embedding resources in a console app is simple, but I'm not sure whether that's what you're really after.

Comment: Right, sorry.  The initial console application installs the MSI, then it copies a second console application (which checks the bitlocker status) to the public folder, then it sets a windows task schedule to run that file intermittently.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is the problem? It's still not clear to me. You appear to understand how to embed resources in a console app, although your `ExecuteEmbeded` code contains a lot of duplication. It's not clear why anything other than the `ExecuteEmbeded` code is relevant here. Do we really need to know what it's doing with bitlocker? It doesn't help that "I can't seem to get [...] to be redistributable" doesn't actually describe what's happening.

Comment: What I need is a single console application (exe) that will contain the .dll that makes the Task Schedule code work, the msi that contains the installer, and the second console application that sets the registry settings that show the encryption status of the drive.

Comment: Rather than explaining in comments, you should edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: Do you need it to embed the .NET framework too?  Why does this need to be a console app instead of an installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you are trying to write a self extracting installer, which typically works in two stages:

1. Unpack the embedded resources to a temporary folder
2. Begin execution using the files in the temporary folder

You can do this in C# by including the files as "Embedded Resources" and save them to disk using something like the following:

```
string pathToSomeMsi = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var resStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("theMsi.msi"))
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(pathToSomeMsi))
{
    resStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

installMsi(pathToSomeMsi);
```

That being said, I would recommend you *not* try to write your own installer (or bootstrapper), as it gets complicated relatively quickly when dealing with uninstall and repairs.  Just use the tools built for this purpose.  MSI includes ways to add scheduled tasks (a custom action [vbs or .net] comes to mind), and most good installer packages include a bootstrapper.

Look at Wix, dotNetInstaller, NSIS, or similar.